# Check if a given word is a palindrome

Tags: java, methods, palindrome

I am trying to write a method to check if a given word is a palindrome, but as of now it does not work. I suspect the error lies within the if-statement and the fact that you don't compare objects such as strings with `==` but instead with `equals`, is that right? However Java does not allow me to write: `if (firstHalf.charAt(i).equals(secondHalf.charAt(j)))`, so what can I do to make it work? Are there other errors in the code?

```java
public static boolean isPalindrome(String string) {
    String firstHalf = string.substring(0, string.length() / 2);
    String secondHalf = string.substring(string.length() / 2, string.length());
    for (int i = 0; i <= firstHalf.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = secondHalf.length(); j <= 0; j--) {
            if (firstHalf.charAt(i) == secondHalf.charAt(j)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You can use == for individual characters, this is fine. Your loop for j decrements, so you should check j>=0 instead of j<=0 (go on while j is zero or more).

Comment: You also return true as soon as you find a match, which is wrong. Everything needs to match for the string to be a palindrome, not only the first and last characters

Answer (score 2):

Why not do it this way?

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String string){
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(string);  
  sb.reverse();  
  return sb.toString().equals(string);
}
```

Comment: Very nice code, quite poor performance if the strings can be long. Of course, since this is most certainly some kind of homework, performance does not matter; however, since this is most certainly some kind of homework, it is probably more instructive to use the loops.

Answer (score 1):

Your character test was backwards.  All of the comparisons have to be equal for the String to be a palindrome.

Also, splitting the `String` is unnecessary.  You can logically split the `String` with two indices.

Try this code.

```
    public static boolean isPalindrome(String string) {
        int frontIndex = 0;
        int backIndex = string.length() - 1;
        while (frontIndex < backIndex) {
            if (string.charAt(frontIndex++) != string.charAt(backIndex--)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

you can make each character a String like so
`String s1 = "" + c1;`
and then compare them with `.equals(s1, s2)`

Or you can use the `Character` class which is a wrapper around primitive `character`.
That would also enable you to use `c1.equals(c2)`

Comment: there's no need for equals here.

Comment: Where? In the first way?

Comment: in OP's code, there's nothing wrong with == comparison of chars